# How to create thumbnail of XLSX and PPTX files

Tags: java, apache-poi, powerpoint, xlsx

I am trying to create a thumbnail of XLSX and PPTX files using Apache POI. I'm noticing that some MS Office files already have a thumbnail which POI can extract, however, other files do not have a thumbnail and POI returns null in those cases.

For the files that do not have a thumbnail, how can I create one for them? I would just need a thumbnail of the first page.

Below is how I get thumbnail using Apache POI:

```
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
POIXMLProperties props = wb.getProperties();
if (props!=null) {
  if (props.getThumbnailImage()!=null) {
     byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(props.getThumbnailImage())
  }
  else { //what should I do for files that do not already have a thumbnail?
    //?
  }
}
```

Comment: POI can only render images of PPT/X - look at [PPTX2PNG](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xslf/util/PPTX2PNG.java)

Comment: @kiwiwings: And PowerPoint is the only one Microsoft Office application which creates thumbnail.jpeg in /docProps/ by default while saving the file. So `apache poi` is not a big help here ;-).

Comment: Are there any alternatives?